# SWT- equal weights to GridLayout row elements?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, grid-layout

I'm trying to add 7 `Text` widgets to a `GridLayout` row.
I want them all to be of the same width, but they come out funky:

[image]

```
//Columns
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setEditable(true);
        data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP,true,false,1,1);
        text.setLayoutData(data);
        cols.add(text);
    }
```

Things I've tried:

- Almost any combination of FILL/TOP and true/false to the GridData constructor (I was desperate).
- Setting `data.minimumWidth` and `data.widthHint` to (window width)/7.

Yet the widgets are always in varying degrees of disarray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify this on the `GridLayout` constructor, second parameter:

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(7, true);
```

specifies 7 columns of equal width.

You can also use

```
layout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to put the widgets in a composite with a `GridLayout` layout, so that only they will be affected by the equal width; but that's the same idea :-)